# Access content of external css using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Its easy to get the internal css code like:

```
var css = '';
$('style').each(function(){
     css+=$(this).html();
});
```

Now if there is an external link for a css file like:

```
<link href="style.css" />
```

Is there anyway to know what css codes are available using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to know what css codes are available using javascript/jquery?

Yes. There is a [`styleSheets` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) containing [`StyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet) objects, most of which will be [`CSSStyleSheet` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), which have a `cssRules` property (just `rules` on old IE) which is a [`CSSRuleList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList) containing [`CSSRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) objects. It doesn't matter whether the styleshet is external (via `link`) or inline (via `style`).

Example:

```js
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function(sheet, index) {
  if (sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules) {
    log("Sheet #" + index);
    forEach.call(sheet.cssRules || css.rules, function(rule, ri) {
      log("- Rule #" + ri + ": " + rule.cssText);
    });
  } else {
    log("Sheet #" + index + " is not a CSSStyleSheet");
  }
});
function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('pre');
  p.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(msg)
  );
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
.bar {
  color: red;
}
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `.cssRules` will probably be inaccessible if the stylesheet is from another domain.